# What is the proper way to label a link with a background image?

Tags: html

If I am using a background image in an anchor tag as a menu, what is the best way to provide a text label equivalent for screen readers and SEO?

Assume the HTML is like this:

```
<h2><a class='menuItem1'></a></h2>
```

And the CSS is like this

```
.menuItem1 {
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:25px;
    background-image:url(../Images.menuitem1.png);
}
```

Should I use `title="..."` as well at `alt="..."` on the `A` tag? My test using the Lynx browser seems to only show a label if there is text in the `A` tag as well.

Comment: There is no alt attribute for the a tag. This attribute applies to the img tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alt` only exists on the `<img>` tag. If your image is actually a meaningful part of the web page, and not just stylistic, then you can just use an actual `<img>` tag with an `alt` attribute.

Alternatively, you could put the actual text inside the `<a>` tag, and hide it using CSS. Since `display: none` will also hide it from screen readers, you would need to instead hide it with something like `text-indent:-9999px;`

Answer (score 0):

The `alt` attribute does not exist on the `a` tag. Thus, you should use `title`. Alternatively, you could create an actual image with the `img` tag and set the `alt` attribute for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<h2><a class='menuItem1'>Text to be only seen by screen readers</a></h2>

.menuItem1 {
  text-indent:-9999px;
}
```